# SQL query to get expected result

Tags: sql, mysql, join

This is my DB schema

```
Table_A
-id 
-status

Table_B
-id

Table_A_has_B
-id
-id_A
-id_B
```

I need to select all records from Table_B, where all associated Table_A records has `status=1` and if a Table_B record  hasn't any associated Table_A also should be selected.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (id int(2),status int(1));
INSERT INTO table_a (id, status)
VALUES (1,1),(2,0),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1);

CREATE TABLE table_b (id int(2));
INSERT INTO table_b (id) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

CREATE TABLE table_a_has_b (id int(2),id_A int(2),id_B int(2));
INSERT INTO table_a_has_b (id, id_A, id_B)
VALUES(1, 1, 1),(2, 2, 1),(3, 3, 1),(4, 4, 2),(5, 5, 2),(6, 3, 4),(7, 4, 4);
```

The query should select:

```
+----+
|b.id|
+----+
|   2|
|   3|
|   4|
+----+
```

- Id 1 shouldn't be selected because one of its table_a records has status=0
- Id 2 and 4 are should be selected because all its table_a records has status=1
- Id 3 should be selected because don't has table_a records associated, another point of view for the same criterion is: Id 3 should be selected because don't have any table_a records where status=0

Comment: First, there is no entry in the middle table for b_id = 3 so why does it show in your output? Second, there is an entry for b_id = 1 and it is associated with a Table_A row where status = 1 so why does it not show in your output?

Comment: @Thomas: I just added the explanation about resultset expected

Comment: Ok. Only now does it make sense what you are trying achieve. I've updated my answer that provides a solution to your puzzle.

Comment: +1 for providing sample inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select ...
From Table_B As B
    Left Join   (
                Select AB.id_B, A.id, A.status
                From Table_A_has_B As AB
                    Join Table_A As A
                        On A.id = AB.id_A
                Where A.status = 1
                ) As Z
        On Z.id_B = B.id
```

This portion of the original post is not clear: `if a Table_B record hasn't any associated Table_A also should be selected.`.

If you only want rows from Table_B then:

```
Select B.*
From Table_B As B
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Table_A_has_B As AB
                    Join Table_A As A
                        On A.id = AB.id_A
                Where A.status = 1
                    And AB.id_B = B.id
                )
```

If you want rows from `Table_ B` where either there are no rows in `Table_A_has_B` for a given `id_B` or where if there are rows it must be associated with a Table_A item where `status` is 1, then :

```
Select B.*
From Table_B As B
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Table_A_has_B As AB
                    Join Table_A As A
                        On A.id = AB.id_A
                Where A.status = 1
                    And AB.id_B = B.id
                )
    Or Not Exists   (
                    Select 1
                    From Table_A_has_B As AB
                    Where AB.id_B = B.id
                    )
```

If what you want is rows from Table_A but only where the status is 1 and for all others a null, then the first query I provided would be the solution. Providing us with some expected output results would obviously help tremendously.

**Edit given update to OP**

Given your update, which only now makes it clear what you are actually trying to achieve, you do the following:

```
Select B.id
From Table_B As B
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From Table_A_has_B As AB
                        Join Table_A As A
                            On A.id = AB.id_A
                    Where A.status <> 1
                        And AB.id_B = B.id
                    )
```

Comment: I've added a test case, and none of your sql snippets are working.

Comment: @texai - "Not working" meaning not producing the output you expect?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT Answer -

```
select b.* from table_B b 
left outer join table_A_has_B ab on ab.id_B = b.id
where ab.id in (
    select id from table_A_has_B ab
    where (id_A in (select id from table_A where status = 1 ))
)
or b.id not in 
(select id_B from table_A_Has_B )
```

OLD answer -

```
select b.* from table_B b
left outer join table_A a on b.id = a.id
where a.status = 1 or a.id is null
```

Comment: Table_A and Table_B are linked through Table_A_has_B, not directly.

Answer (score 0):

By rephrasing your requirement statement to select table_B which does not have associated table_A with status <> 1. I come to the following query statement:

```
select distinct b.* 
from table_B b
left outer join table_A_has_B ab on ab.id_B = b.id
left outer join table_A a on a.id = ab.id_A and a.status <> 1
where a.id is null
```

or

```
select b.* 
from table_B b
where not exists (select null from table_A_has_B ab 
inner join table_A a on a.id = ab.id_A and a.status <> 1
where ab.id_B = b.id)
```